# Error installing VS 2010 SP1

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

when I am installing visual studio 2010 SP1 I get an error.read [POSTS](https://superuser.com/questions/304463/where-can-i-find-the-file-dotfuscatorce-5-0-2500-msi). But still can't figure out why. I tried with the ISO Image also. Always get the error.

I Have installed VS 2010 Ultimate edition.

I tried to install the SP1 found in this [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691)

The error is as follows,

```
The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.
Click OK to try again, or enter alternative path to a folder containing the installation package. 'DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi' in the list` box below`
```

Following is a screenshot of the error

[image]

If anyone can suggest a solution really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edits................................................................................

I did fixed the above error as  Talon06 described in this post. But again get the following error when I proceed through.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this error before ? Does any one have idea of How I can proceed through. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found this answer at 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/57de87cb-607f-4c49-baa3-128eb0fbebfd

This link will allow you to download the Dotfuscator file you need.
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208995&clcid=0x409

Post From Social.msdn.mcrosoft.com

> You can download the package directly from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208995&clcid=0x409 and pass
>   that if prompted. If you're not being prompted for source, you'll need
>   to create a local layout of SP1 by downloading the SP1 setup
>   application, then from a command prompt type:
>
> VS10sp1-KB983509.exe /createlayout "%TEMP%\VS2010SP1"
>
> When that completes, you can run setup.exe from that directory.

Comment: Thanks Talon06, Again it asks for 'FSharpRedist2.0.msi'. Why this installation asks so many .msi files to user to give the path. Is there any way that available if I can find the installation itself to complete the task?

Comment: According to what I've found in my research it should be in the VS2010 folder where ever it was extracted.
I would maybe try doing a search for "*.msi" without quotes. This will show all msi files and should allow you to find what you need.

Comment: You mean setup file? I just type *.msi but wasn't there any. Can you please explain a bit. Now I am struggling for this 4 four days. searching everywhere...

Comment: To search for the msi do a windows search and set it to search your C: drive.
I don't know where the VS2010 folder would end up, but it should be extracted when you run the setup file.
Otherwise, if you still have the iso version try looking at the folders on the iso and see if it has the file you need.

Comment: I did a search in C: Drive. But did't find any. Is it there in yours??

Comment: I didn't find the msi, but I found an exe in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\FSharpRedist20

Comment: I found the file in the setup ISO image. I extracted it and gave the path. When I give the path for that it gives the following error message "PATH/FSharpRedist2.0.msi is not a valid installation package for the product Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime. Try to find the installation package FSharpRedist.msi in a folder in which you can install Microsoft Visual F#2.0 Runtime"

Comment: Have you tried just running the FSharpRedist2.0.msi by itself without the VS2010 installer calling it?

Comment: No, I didn't. Because it doesn't allow to run that since the SP1 Installation is happening. If I want to run that have to stop SP1 installation and have to run that....

Comment: Run the MSI before starting the SP1 installation, then after that run the SP1 installation

Comment: Found the Visual Studio F# Runtime 2.0 sp1 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15834 HTH

Comment: Uninstall the F# Runtime with the link @user89861 gave, and then run the VS2010 installer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and used Microsoft's **FixIt** utility which you can download here. http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/.

I had already installed a number of English Express versions which had SP1 applied. I then tried to install the German VS2010 Professional and got a number of problems like the one described above.